# jQuery click on anchor tag reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery

As many other threads and external forums suggest, I've tried placing e.preventDefault() (while passing e as parameter, not in code sample) in every place imaginable, but it doesn't prevent the anchor from reloading the page. When I step through the debugger, it will assign every div with scrollNav the click event, but when I click on the div-link it just reloads the page and the debugger does not stop on any lines in the highlightSelection function. Another method I've tried is to use an anonymous function inside this.click and place e.preventDefault() as the first line, but it does nothing.

I also don't really understand why you would want to place e.preventDefault() as so many others have suggested. Isn't it basically saying return false? That may stop a link from reloading the page, but won't it prevent the code in the method from executing?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.scrollNav').each(initSideNavForSelection);

}); // end ready

function initSideNavForSelection() {
    this.click(highlightSelection);
}

function highlightSelection() {
    var selectedDataID = this.attr("data-id");

jQuery('.scrollNav').each(function() {
    if (this.attr("data-id") === selectedDataID) {
        this.addClass("selected");
    } else {
        this.removeClass("selected");
    }
})
```

}

Comment: If possible, try reproduce your problem using either the stack snippet in your question or jsfiddle.

Comment: Just tried JSFiddle. Same thing is happening there too. The preview loads back to the top.

Comment: Please share your fiddle link.

Comment: Shoot, sorry. Forgot to include that: http://jsfiddle.net/7e89abzg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I had to do to get your codes to run. You can take a link at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/1kkyhmw5/).

Here's the list:

1. Add JQuery as the framework to be used for your fiddle, under the **Frameworks & Extensions** section on the top left corner.
2. Remove the broken `onclick="Event.stop(event)"` inlined attribute as `Event` is undefined.
3. Replace the usage of `this` with `$(this)` in both your `initSideNavForSelection()` and `highlightSelection()` functions. `this` represents a DOM object and `$(this)` is a JQuery wrapper around `this`. The latter will respond to JQuery methods like `.click()`, but not the former.

So far, there is no page reload in your fiddle, with or without `e.preventDefault()`.

Finally, in addition to `event.preventDefault()`, `return false` also calls `event.stopProgagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM, before terminating the callback execution immediately. A call to `event.preventDefault()` doesn't terminate the function call immediately.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I was having alot of trouble with this being new to js and jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Add `onclick="return false;"` to the anchor.
OR change `initSideNavForSelection` function to

```
this.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefaults();
    highlightSelection();
});
```

either works

Comment: I've tried both, neither the onclick to false or anonymous function set on click work. As before, the page just reloads on click.